# How can i Validate when Value of one row is similar with one another

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

[image]

I want to validate when Contact Type value have True Primary while saving so that There is only one Contact Type Value That is Primary,

How can i handle it Using jquery or Javascript :(

Thanks

```
var row = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=workerId]").val();
            var contactValue = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=contactValue]").val();
            var contactType = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=contactType]").val();
            var isPrimary = obj.closest("tr").find("input[name=isPrimary]").val();
            // get the value of  the checkbox in edit modal window
            if (isPrimary === 'true') {
                $('#chkEditWorkerIsPrimary').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $('#chkEditWorkerIsPrimary').removeAttr('checked');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of rows where isPrimary column has true value and check it matches 1. Otherwise show warning or error message

```
var isPrimaryCount = $('#testTable').find('tr input[name=isPrimary][value=true]').length
if (isPrimaryCount < 1 || isPrimaryCount > 1) {
    alert('message to user')
}
```